# Auth::user Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using laravel 5.3 and using Multi-Auth Hesto Package. 
I used view composers to pass my current Auth::user to Welcome.blade

I already logged in my Customer/Home.blade but when I go to Welcome.blade and accessing the current Auth::useran error says "Trying to get property of non-object"

Here's my Viewmcomposers/AuthComposer.php

```
class AuthComposer
{
    public $currentUser;

 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->currentUser = Auth::User();
        View::share([ 'currentUser' => $this->currentUser ]);
    }

   public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('currentUser', Auth::user()->name);
    }
}
```

App/Providers/ComposerServiceProvider.php

```
 public function boot()
    {

    view()->composer('welcome', function ($view) 
    {
        $currentUser = Customer::where('name', Auth::user()->name);
        $view->with('welcome', $currentUser );    
    }); 
    }
```

Config/App.php

```
 App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
```

My routes for customer

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    $users[] = Auth::user();
    $users[] = Auth::guard()->user();
    $users[] = Auth::guard('customer')->user();
    return view('customer.home');
})->name('home');
```

And I just call this in my routes/web.php for my welcome.blade

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@showWelcome');
```

Comment: any stacktrace - that pile of function calls that shown when laravel *went wrong*?

Comment: I updated my question and my line 18 would be this $view->with('currentUser', Auth::user()->name); But when I remove the ->name it shows nothing. Welcome.blade sees me as a guest

Comment: well, try to put `dd(Auth::user())` just before your line 18 in `ComposerServiceProvider.php`, i wonder if the user actually never auntheticated and `Auth::user()` returns null.

Comment: it returns 'null'

Comment: ugh, well, how did you handle user login?

Comment: I'm using a package. All home.blade successfully reads the Auth::user.

Comment: hmm, weird. anyway, after you got that error, does the other page still sees you as  a logged in user?

Comment: In my home.blade - Yes.

Comment: hmm, do you mind to post your `route.php` - i wonder whether the controller that handles `welcome` is not belong to `auth` middleware group.. (or just check it, i did not wish to clutter the post)

Comment: I updated my question. Would you mind if we can talk via email to solve this problem. So I can send the codes. If its okay

Answer (score 0):

Use Auth;

in top of page it may help you.

Show me complete error .